# How to print image from OID data type over PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

I want to display a images data from postgres DB into web browser. So the users no need access the DB directly. The image it self saved to the OID data type.

Here my code:

```
$result = pg_query($dbconn, "SELECT raw FROM image WHERE id = 14;");


    if (!$result) {
        echo "An error occured.\n";
        exit;
    }

    $xml_result="<resultxml>";

    $num = pg_num_fields($result);

    while($row = pg_fetch_array($result)){

    $xml_result.="<record>"; 
        for ($i=0; $i < $num; $i++)
            {
                $xml_result .= "<".pg_field_name($result, $i).">".$row[$i]."</".pg_field_name($result, $i).">"; 
            } 
    $xml_result.="</record>";
    }
    $xml_result.="</resultxml>";

    echo $xml_result;

    //SECOND CODE
// $raw = pg_fetch_result($res, 'raw');
 //header('Content-type: image/png');
 //echo pg_unescape_bytea($raw);

 $reg = pg_fetch_object($result);

print pg_loopen($reg -> oid);
```

When i run above code, in xml result only print the OID value: eg. 1234. But if I run the second script the browser showing blank page (black) with small square at the center. Any one have experience with this?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using PostgreSQL >= 9.0.

From the PHP doc [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-unescape-bytea.php)

> PostgreSQL 9.0 introduced "hex" as the new default format for encoding
>   binary data. Because `pg_unescape_bytea` only works with the old
>   "escape" format, you need to do `pg_query('SET bytea_output = "escape";');` 
>   before executing your select queries.

You can read about it in the PostreSQL doc [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/datatype-binary.html).

Alternatively you can configure PSQL to use the old escape by running

```
ALTER USER username SET bytea_output = 'escape';
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer tried it, but still showing black page with small square.

Comment: Are you sure the result is properly saved and is an actual valid img?

Comment: Yes the image is saved but I still can't to view it over browser. I will let you know after try several ways.

Comment: Can you give me what does the image look like before you save it to the db and what does $raw looks like?

Comment: Hi @Martin Dimitrov, after several tried, the image print showing the the `\x3c726573756c....` I used this code: 

`$rawdata = pg_escape_bytea($xml_result);
echo $rawdata;

//$escaped = pg_escape_bytea($xml_result);
//echo $escaped;

$imgData = base64_encode($rawdata);
$img = "<img src= 'data:image/png;base64, $imgData' />";
print($img);`

 
before I just got the oid data like a number only (23576). The image it self it just a standard image i got from google :)